# Adding numbers in an array for every given array size - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to add every 12 numbers in an array. For example

```
double[] addMe = {147.04, 147.66, 148.27, 148.89, 149.51, 150.13, 150.76, 151.39, 152.02, 152.65, 153.29, 153.29, 
                10, 20 ,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120};
```

I am able to add all the numbers inside the array by doing the following

```
double sum = 0;
for (double i : addMe){
                sum += i;
            }
System.out.println(sum);
```

Which gives me `2584.9`.

But I am trying to get sum of every 12 numbers in the array which should give me

```
1804.84
780.0
```

How should I do that?

thanks.

Comment: Any reason for the uncheck and answer switch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double sum=0.0;
for(int i=0;i<addMe.length;i++)
{
  if(i%12==0 && i!=0)
  {
    System.out.println(sum);
    sum=0;
  }

  sum +=addMe[i];
}
```

Comment: Close, but your don't want to print for `i=0` and you do want to print after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the index and current sum and only output the current sum when the index is 12:

```
    int index = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    for(double i: addMe){
        index++;
        sum+=i;
        if (index == 12){
            System.out.println(sum);
            index = 0;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
```