# Adding remaining numbers in an array - Java

Tags: java, arrays

So I asked a question earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753377/adding-numbers-in-an-array-for-every-given-array-size-java), in which the numbers in an array should be added together till the length of 12.

Now, how would I add the remaining numbers, lets say

```
double[] addMe = {147.04, 147.66, 148.27, 148.89, 149.51, 150.13, 150.76, 151.39, 152.02, 152.65, 153.29, 153.29, 
                10, 20 ,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120, 10,20};
```

from the above I get an answer of

```
1804.9
780.0
1804.9
```

but it missed the last two numbers `10 and 20`, how would I add both of them if the count is not equal to 12?

Thanks.

Comment: It is even stated in the comment of the accepted answer from the other question that you need to add a print after the loop ;)

Answer (score 3):

modify this much, You are adding all the numbers , it just you are not printing the last sum if elements are less than 12

```
 double sum=0.0;
for(int i=0;i<addMe.length;i++)
{
  if(i%12==0 && i!=0)
  {
    System.out.println(sum);
    sum=0;
  }

  sum +=addMe[i];
}
System.out.println(sum);//Just add this outside the loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (If you require to print `sum` within loop, else the above answer by @L-X is better solution).

```
double sum=0.0;
for(int i=0;i<addMe.length;i++)
{
  if(i%12==0 && i!=0)
  {
    System.out.println(sum);
    sum=0;
  }    
  sum +=addMe[i];
  if(i==addMe.length-1)
      System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to print it out of the loop, since it becomes empty before it can be evenly divided by 12, it doesn't successfully print, that is why you add the print statement outside of the loop, so when it finishes, it will print the remaining sum.

```
    double[] addMe = {147.04, 147.66, 148.27, 148.89, 149.51, 150.13, 150.76, 151.39, 152.02, 152.65, 153.29, 153.29, 
            10, 20 ,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120, 10,20};

    double sum=0.0;
    int y = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<addMe.length;i++)
    {

      if(i%12==0 && i!=0)
      {
          y++;
        System.out.print(y+": "+sum+"\n");
        sum=0;
      }else{
          sum +=addMe[i];
      }

    }
    y++;
    System.out.println(y+": "+sum);
```

**Output**

```
1: 1804.9
2: 770.0
3: 20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Sum {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        double[] addMe = {
            147.04, 147.66, 148.27, 148.89, 149.51, 150.13, 150.76, 151.39, 152.02, 152.65, 153.29, 153.29,
            10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 10, 20
        };
        double sum = 0.0;
        double remainder = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < addMe.length; i++) {
            if (i >= (addMe.length - addMe.length / 12)) {
                remainder = remainder + addMe[i];
            }
            if (i % 12 == 0 && i != 0) {
                System.out.println(sum);
                sum = 0;
            }

            sum += addMe[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Remainder sum: " + remainder);
    }
}
```